# How convert an object presence into an integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do something like :

```rb
@count = @product.possible_loans.count + @product.current_loan.present?
```

But `present` is not an integer, it's a boolean.

How can I convert true to 1 and false to 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@count = @product.possible_loans.count + (@product.current_loan.present? ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Ruby's ternary operator, like so

```
@product.current_loan.present? ? 1 : 0
```

Thus, in your case

```
@count = @product.possible_loans.count + (@product.current_loan.present? ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your making this to complicated.

```
@count = @product.possible_loans.count
@count += 1 if @product.current_loan.present?
```

This is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by davidb seems to be most readable for a human, but if you want exactly to  convert true or false to 1 or 0, you can utilise the fact that object_id of the 'true' object in Ruby is 2 and 'false' object_id is 0. So

```
@count = @product.possible_loans.count+@product.current_loan.present?.object_id/2
```

will work as you want: 0/2 will be converted to 0 (false) and 2/2 to 1 (true). But that'll make the operation a bit tricky for others.

Note that nil object has object_id 4, so do not try to cancel the 'present?' – you'll get the wrong result :)